# Using an Arduino as a Human Interface Device that sends analog inputs

Tags: usb

I would like to have an arduino board act as a human interface device that can send analog inputs like joysticks.

As it currently stands I see two aproaches to this issue:

1. Use the arduino hid library and program all the reports in myself. This should be fairly simple but I can't seem to find any recourses that I actually understand. I get the idea of reports but I dont get how the report format is described to the OS. I also dont understand how drivers on the pc side of things play into this whole equation.
2. Write some software that makes a serial connection with the arduino and uses java's robot functionality (or similar) to controll a joystick, if even possible. This method would be much easier but would feel overall less polished.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Option 3: Use a different board that supports hid joysticks out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary does my first aproach. The limitations one what board it can be will not be an issue because I have an extra 32u4 board.